# Get return value of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I`ve a code like this:

on **getImage.js** file it calls a API and get some data from it:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const url = "api.something.example"

const getImage = async url => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const json =  await response.json()
        console.log(json)
        return json
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = getImage(url)
```

and then on **index.js** it calls the previous file and expects for the object that comes from the API

```
const getImage = require("./getImage")
console.log(getImage)
```

But what prints on the console it is: *Promise {  }*
There is a simple way to get the object data?

Comment: what is ouput of `console.log(json)`

Comment: @DhavalDarji it was Promise {<Pending>}. But I guess I`ve found a fix.

Comment: That's great ! Thank You.